# Spark Streaming frequency

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

[In the example](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/streaming/StatefulNetworkWordCount.scala)
the streaming frequency is 1 seconds however I do not want to print the contents of the word-counts every minute and resent the  word counts again back to 0 every minute. How can I do that ?

I have to print per minute work counts with streaming frequency of 1 second.
I though of using scala schedulers but then there can be concurrency issues.

My algorithm is as follows:

1. Read the words every 1 second
2. Do cumulative work count for 60 seconds
3. After the end of every 60 second (1 minute) print the workcounts and resent the counters to zero.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use Window function of Spark Streaming.

Here is some Sample code: -

```
//val sparkConf = new SparkConf()
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(1))
//Assuming you are getting some Random lines through Socket opened at port 4099 
val lines = streamCtx.socketTextStream("localhost", 4099,MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER_2)
//Window Duration set to 60 Seconds
val windowStream = lines.window(60)
//Now leverage "windowStream" and do further calculations
//Your "windowStream" will contain the data received in last 60 seconds
```

For more Info refer on "Window" functions, refer to http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream

Comment: Thanks how can I send the windowStream calucations to a KafkaTopic or some other system after every 60 seconds ? I know how to send it but I dont know how to wait for for 60 seconds before sending.

Comment: @Soumitra - Why do you want to wait for 60 Seconds for sending it to Kafka Topic?

Comment: The input frequency for the target system is 60 seconds, I know I can still write to kafka topic every second but that will result in unnecessary traffic .

Comment: @Soumitra - ideally Systems like Kafka are meant to handle such high frequency streaming data but still if you want a 60 minutes interval, then there are 2 options: - Use the second param of window function - "slidingWindow" which will ensure that your RDD's are created after the duration specified by "slidingWindow".